# Through which medium is most of the heat transferred down (downwards) a glass tube filled with water: the glass walls or the water column?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

If a much hotter object is attached to the tube from the outside, and the heat in question is transferred to the part of the tube that is below the source of heat, so there is no convection. ¨
The conductivity of glass is a bit higher than that of water (0.8 to 0.6), but the area of water perpendicular to the flow of heat is way larger than that of the glass, so I think that almost all of the heat will be transferred through the water column. Is my reasoning correct?
Is Fourier's law applicable in this case?

Comment: If the cross sectional area of the tube was extremely large, and the thickness of the glass was held constant, which do you think would win out?

Comment: @ChetMiller It is extremely large relative to the thickness of the wall. Yeah, the water column will win out. I wanted to make sure.